# Ratio vs Difference in terms of growth

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance, percentages

Suppose we have the following data:

```
  start date      end date       quantity
  01/05/2014       07/05/2015        5
  07/06/2015       02/06/2016        8
```

What is the logic of the following expression: $$ \left[\left(\frac{8}{5} \right)^{360/215}-1 \right] \times 100 \% = 1.197 \%$$

Assume that a year is $360$ days. Intuitively I want to find the percentage difference between the two quantities for a year. When I do the following:

$$ \frac{\frac{8-5}{5}}{215/360} \times 100 \% = 1.005 \%$$

I get a percentage that is close to the above but not the same. Maybe I can take the logarithm of the first expression to get something similar to the second expression?

Note that  `215`  is the number of days between  `07/06/2015`  and  `02/06/2015` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different models for the growth.  The one you ask about assumes the growth is a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series), that it starts at $5$ and is multiplied by some number $r$ each day.  The second day you would have quantity $5r$, the third $5r^2$ and the $216$th day $5r^{215}$.  They are then calculating $r$ and extending the growth to a year.  On the first day of the new year the quantity is $5r^{360}=5\left(\frac 85\right)^{(360/215)}\approx 10.984$  which is about $2.197$ times the first day.    The calculation of the increase is not correct and should yield $119.7\%$.

Your formula assumes the growth is an [arithmetic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression), that it grows by a fixed amount each day.  The first day you have quantity $5$, the second $5+d$, the third $5+2d$ and the $216$th day $5+215d$.  On the first day of the new year year you will have quantity $5+360d$.    You can calculate $d=\frac {8-5}{215}\approx 0.014$, giving a quantity on the first day of the new year of about $10.023$, which would be an increase of about $100.5\%$  You should not be dividing the growth in $215$ days by $5$ if you consider it an arithmetic series.

Which model of growth is correct (if either) is not a mathematical question.

Comment: Why is it $5r^{360} = 5 \left(\frac{8}{5} \right)^{360/215}$ instead of $5r^{360} = 5 \left(\frac{8}{5} \right)^{360}$?

Comment: Because we had $5r^{215}=8,$ so $r=(\frac 85)^{1/215}$.  We want to raise that to the $360$ power for the increase over $360$ days.